# Javascript Animation in background and website code in the front

Tags: javascript, css, animation, web

I would love to make a website with this code in the background and then a website with a menu bar in top as naviagtion and then add some images and text and footer.

I just don't know if this would work and how I should make it on top of the javascript animation...

Here are the code, which is free to use.

https://codepen.io/akm2/pen/rHIsa

Here are html:

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<div class="info">Click to add gravity point.</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Thanks / Joe

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code you have tried so far. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is to set the [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) of the canvas element to -1. You can then build the site as you normally would, because the canvas is underneath the standard z-index.

```
#c {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to add z-index :-).